# os.rename Error "The system cannot find the path specified"

Tags: python, batch-rename

Similar questions have been asked about this on SO already, and I actually got this code from a post on here, but I am having trouble debugging this error.

```py
import os

paths = (os.path.join(root, filename)
        for root, _, filenames in os.walk(r'C:\Users\kevin\Diamond Line JPEGS\Diamond Line JPEGS')
        for filename in filenames)

for path in paths:
    # the '#' in the example below will be replaced by the '-' in the filenames in the directory
    newname = path.replace(' ', '_')
    if newname != path:
        print(path)
        print(newname)
        os.rename(path, newname)
```

When I use `os.rename(path,path)`, it works, so I know the problem must be with newname, and most likely my lack of understanding as to how `os.rename` works. It doesn't believe that newname exists as highlighted by the following error:

```
[WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Users\\kevin\\Diamond Line JPEGS\\Diamond Line JPEGS\\Test 01.jpg' -> 'C:\\Users\\kevin\\Diamond_Line_JPEGS\\Diamond_Line_JPEGS\\Test_01.jpg'
```

I didn't think the new directory name needed to "exist" in order for you to rename it, so I am quite confused. I have read the documentation, and I still don't understand why it is failing. The Python file I am using is in the same folder (although I don't imagine that should make a difference here).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use os.renames instead of os.rename. the problem is that os.rename only changes the name of the uppermost directory so in your case it looks for "Test 01.jpg" inside "C:\Users\kevin\Diamond_Line_JPEGS\Diamond_Line_JPEGS\" which doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you soooo much. I didn't realise it was renaming the folder names as well (should have been more careful). Would I be right in saying that if the folder names didn't have spaces then os.rename would have worked?
Once again, thank you so so much.

Comment: I think so yeah. I'm assuming it worked for you so I'm glad I helped.